# Computing worldMatrix in maya API

Tags: c++, api, matrix, maya

I have an issue on my custom DG Node.
I am using the API of Maya in C++.

Here is the following setup:

- I have an inputWorldMatrix attribute
- I have outputTranslationX, Y and Z attributes

Now my goal is to create the same affect like a decomposeMatrix

I plug in the worldMatrix of a transform(objA) into my inputWorldMatrix attr of my CustomNode and connect its outputTranslationX,Y,Z into another transform's(objB) tx, ty, tz attr.

The issue is that after I did all the connections the transform node objB is not affected
anyhow. In my compute function when I cout << translation.x << endl; it shows me that it is getting dirty(what it should) and that this value is not changing.

My question: where is the issue?

Here is the code of the compute function:

MStatus WorldMatrix::compute(const MPlug& plug, MDataBlock& data)
{

```
MStatus status;

if((plug == aOutTranslationX) || (plug == aOutTranslationY) || (plug == aOutTranslationZ))
{
    //get worldMatrix dataHandle
    MDataHandle hInputMatrix = data.inputValue(aWorldMatrix, &status);
    CHECK_MSTATUS_AND_RETURN_IT(status);   

    //get the worldMatrix and the translation
    MMatrix mInputMatrix = hInputMatrix.asMatrix();       
    MTransformationMatrix mTransMat(mInputMatrix);
    MVector translation = mTransMat.getTranslation(MSpace::kWorld);

    cout << translation.x << translation.y << translation. z << endl;    

    //get outMatrixX data
    MDataHandle hOutMatrixX = data.outputValue(aOutTranslationX, &status);
    CHECK_MSTATUS_AND_RETURN_IT(status);

    //get outMatrixY data
    MDataHandle hOutMatrixY = data.outputValue(aOutTranslationY, &status);
    CHECK_MSTATUS_AND_RETURN_IT(status);

    //get outMatrixZ data
    MDataHandle hOutMatrixZ = data.outputValue(aOutTranslationZ, &status);
    CHECK_MSTATUS_AND_RETURN_IT(status);

    float outX = translation.x;//do some compute stuff
    float outY = translation.y;//do some compute stuff 
    float outZ = translation.z;//do some compute stuff

    //set outMatrixX with outX value
    hOutMatrixX.setFloat(outX);

    //set outMatrixY with outY value
    hOutMatrixY.setFloat(outY);

    //set outMatrixZ with outZ value
    hOutMatrixZ.setFloat(outZ);

    data.setClean(plug);
    return MS::kSuccess;
}
else
{
    return MS::kUnknownParameter;
}
```

}

My aWorldMatrix attribute is created by an MFnMatrixAttribute and it is set as MFnMatrixAttribute::kFloat in the initialize function

And of course it is affecting the OutputTranslationX, Y, Z attributes.
I guess also I need to do a conversion of the vector to a float(for setFloat), but don't know how. It would be awesome if someone could help me out. 
Thanks in advance!!

Cheerio
turkish engineer

Answer (score 1):

This is a general Maya thing **dirtying** does not make things compute. But rather notifies Maya that compute may be needed. If there is no item in the scene that is last in line, a shape or a GUI item that need the value, then Maya will just not compute this for you. So the problem is not in compute it is in the scene or in affects network.

So connect the output if your plug to something like a transform that has shapes as children etc.* And you will see Maya reacting. Mayas just optimizing you away as redundant. If this does not work then your attribute affects is wrong.

Since your not showing the code for your attribute affects section its impossible to say anything other than this (other than claiming it is ok, but i guess it may still be problematic). So to give a better answer we need to know your affects network.

As such the code you gave can not be used to debug the situation so most SO users will just ignore you.

```
 * No it is not enough to connect to a node. The node needs to be one 
   that updates the graphics state somehow.
```